# URL rewriting and get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am currently building a website where the content of pages come from a database.

To construct my SQL statement, I use the parameters in the URL and until now everything worked fine.

Now I would like to rewrite the URLs to have clean URL, so by default my URLs look like:

```
lunettes-collection.php?supplier=all&type=vue
```

I wrote a rule to convert this URL like

```
lunettes-collection-vue.html
```

But now when I reach this URL I obviously cannot get the parameter `type=vue`.

What is the best practice to handle such situation?

Answer (score 0):

With .htaccess you can do that

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

#Rewrite lunettes-collection.php?supplier=all&type=vue to 
#lunettes-collection/all/vue
RewriteRule ^lunettes-collection/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+) lunettes-collection.php?supplier=$1&type=$2 [NC,L]
```

Remember that URL will only support letter from a-z and A-Z if you want enable digits add an extra part 0-9

Comment: this only rewrite my url, I do not need to rewrite my URL I need to retrieve a parameters which not exists anymore in the URL.

Comment: @user1628610 Then use $_GET

Comment: That's the problem, when I use $_GET with the new URL `lunettes-collection-vue.html` the value is undefined because there is no more parameters in my URL.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite would not be Such an outcome.

The $_GET will get normal variable.

Please show your Rewrite rules.

I try the Nginx rules is work normal like this.

```
rewrite ^/lunettes-collection-vue.html$ /lunettes-collection.php?supplier=all&type=vue last;
```

Comment: here is the content of my .htaccess `Options +FollowSymlinks 

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^lunettes-collection-([a-z]+)\.html$ lunettes-collection.php?supplier=all&type=$1 [L]`. I do not understand your point. How I can retrieve the paramater from a URL like lunettes-collection-vue.html id the parameters doesn't appear on the URL?